# Carga de imagenes en galeria (No lazyload)

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me arma una galeria:

```
<div class="contenedorGaleria">
<div class="m-p-g">
    <div class="m-p-g__thumbs" data-google-image-layout data-max-height="350">
        <?php
            $pCarpeta="views/image/fotos/";
            $mascaraTotal="*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.PNG, *.JPEG, *.jpeg";
            $total=count(glob($pCarpeta . "/{" . $mascaraTotal . "}",GLOB_BRACE));
            $contador = 1;
            while ( $contador<= $total) {
                echo "<img src='views/image/fotos/thumbnail/".$contador.".jpg' data-full='views/image/fotos/".$contador.".jpg' class='m-p-g__thumbs-img'/>";
                $contador++;
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="m-p-g__fullscreen"></div>
</div>
```

Quiero que las imágenes se carguen en el DOM solo si un total de pixeles de la misma es visible para el usuario para que no se ponga lenta la pagina si las imágenes dentro de la carpeta son muchas, intente usar lazyload pero no lo puedo hacer funcionar porque me choca con dependencias de otros archivos que ya no puedo cambiar.

Como puedo detectar por imagen dentro del while cuanto esta visible en la pantalla sabiendo que siempre el máximo de height es de 350 px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la (in)compatibilidad con [Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Browser_compatibility) no es un obstáculo podes hacer uso de un ["Observador de Intersección"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), este API está diseñado para observar y calcular intersecciones entre elementos, se crea un observer con un callback (funcion que procesa una lista de elementos observados) y unas opciones, en las opciones le das el threshold (límite inferior o ratio de visibilidad) que indica cuanto de cada elemento observado tiene que ser visible dentro del root (por default es el viewport/ventana/pestaña). Para mas claridad un ejemplo práctico:

- a las imágenes les damos un css con un background animado, el `src` lo dejamos indefinido pero lo definimos en un atributo `data-src`
- creamos un observador que cuando un elemento es visible toma el `data-src` se crea una imagen con ese `src` y se le engancha un evento `onload`, esto es para que se cargue por detrás de escena.
- cuando esta imagen se termina de cargar se le asigna el mismo `src` al elemento que origino la movida (como está en cache la imagen aparece automágicamente)
- como efecto adicional se sube la opacidad a normal para lograr un poco de dramatismo

```js
const panoptico = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(
    el => {
      if (el.isIntersecting) {
        let imagen = el.target;
        let foto = document.createElement('img');
        foto.src = imagen.getAttribute('data-src');
        foto.objetivo = imagen;
        foto.onload = (ev) => {
          ev.target.objetivo.src = ev.target.src;
          ev.target.objetivo.style.opacity = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  )
}, {
  threshold: [.75]
});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var lasImagenes = document.querySelectorAll('img.lazyload');
  lasImagenes.forEach(i => i.obs = panoptico.observe(i));

});
```

```css
#scrollArea {
  display: block;
  width: 460px;
  height: 210px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#scrollArea img {
  border: medium none;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img.lazyload {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22 class%3D%22lds-dual-ring%22 preserveAspectRatio%3D%22xMidYMid%22 style%3D%22background%3A0 0%22 viewBox%3D%220 0 100 100%22%3E%3Ccircle cx%3D%2250%22 cy%3D%2250%22 r%3D%2240%22 fill%3D%22none%22 stroke%3D%22%230DD%22 stroke-dasharray%3D%2262.832 62.832%22 stroke-linecap%3D%22round%22 stroke-width%3D%224%22 transform%3D%22rotate%28126 50 50%29%22%3E%3CanimateTransform attributeName%3D%22transform%22 begin%3D%220s%22 calcMode%3D%22linear%22 dur%3D%221s%22 keyTimes%3D%220%3B1%22 repeatCount%3D%22indefinite%22 type%3D%22rotate%22 values%3D%220 50 50%3B360 50 50%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E') !important;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 10%;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollArea">
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=0" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=3" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=6" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=9" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=12" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=15" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=18" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=21" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=24" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=27" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=30" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=33" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=36" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=39" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=42" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=45" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=48" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=51" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=54" class="lazyload" />
  <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/200/?image=57" class="lazyload" />
</div>
```

Comment: A la perfección, muchas gracias!